# asking for change in work assigned to m

Tags: professionalism, communication, career-development

I have newly joined existing project team,i am not happy with the current work assigned to me by the team lead, can i ask my lead for change in module

Comment: possible duplicate of [Requesting a change of project as an intern](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/27671/requesting-a-change-of-project-as-an-intern)

Comment: "newly joined" people should "prove" their competence before making waves. You can "prove" your competence by taking whatever task is assigned to you and complete it enthusiastically, correctly and with a nice degree of quality. Once you gain your lead's confidence then you'll find that you can generally ask for whatever you want and odds are high that you'll get it. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can ask, but you may or may not get the response you're hoping for. You'd need to put a bit of thought into how to approach the subject, with items like:

- why you want to change
- what you'd prefer to do
- why this would be a
  good idea for the COMPANY, not for you

Basically, you need to sell this as an idea to your team leader.